# Problem with USB ports

Tags: usb, usb-c

I just want a quick PCB, and I'm a beginner, so I'm quite confused atr USB-C ports. Could you help me to tell / show ... what should I do?

I'm making a PCB for a keyboard, and I found this:

[image]

J1 is a micro USB port. I'm using an ATMEGA32U4 and i'd like to know where should I put the cables to connect to this USB-C port:

[image]

And if that helps, this is the beginning of my PCB:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB-C socket for USB-A compatible mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627092/usb-c-socket-for-usb-a-compatible-mode) as this has been asked many times.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a good guide on hooking up a USB-C connector (5V @ 3A) https://forum.digikey.com/t/simple-way-to-use-usb-type-c-to-get-5v-at-up-to-3a-15w/7016 Let me know if you have any questions!

Note: Be aware that you typically can't hook up USB-C to a MCU directly. You'll likely need a few caps and a buck converter to convert the 5v to 3.3v (depending on supply)

Edit: Look at the max voltage of the MCU to determine whether you can connect USB-C directly. In this case it should work fine.

Comment: Of course you can hook USB-C directly to MCU just like you can hook a MicroUSB directly to MCU. Where did you get the idea you can't? Plus, this is a link-only answer.

Comment: The ATMEGA32U4 can use a 5.5v supply. I'm more familiar with low-power MCU's which are typically limited to 3.3v and would require step-down circuitry to properly connect USB-C.